# ASP.NET MVC UserControl requires css/javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, code-reuse

I have a user control (a user details form) which has a lot of javascript and css attached to it.
i'm struggling to make my control decalre that it needs a certain file so it will be included in the "head" section of the html.

I also wonder what happens if i enter mutiple instances of a control (the is no InamingContainer or anything similiar).

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370060/how-can-i-include-css-files-from-an-mvc-partial-control

Comment: thank you. i searched for it and couldn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily implemented using [MvcScriptManager](http://www.codeplex.com/MvcScriptManager). Hope this help :)